# Remove key from array of json using circe

Tags: scala, scala-collections, circe

I have a json as:

```
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c"
  },
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1"
  }
]
```

Now, I want to delete the key for `c`. So the result would be:

```
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  },
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1"
  }
]
```

I am using circe, what I have done until now is:

```
parse(entityAs[String]) match {
  case Right(value) =>
    val json = value.hcursor
    val result = json.downArray.downField("c").delete
    println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    println(result.right.as[List[Json]])
         
  case Left(_) =>
}
```

There is some problem with this line

```
val result = json.downArray.downField("c").delete
```

What would be the correct line to delete the key `c` and then convert it back to list of json using circe?

Answer (score 4):

`delete` returns a cursor at the position of the thing the element was deleted from. You want to get back the whole document, you can navigate back to the top with `top`. You'll get back the modified document. Given

```
val doc = parse(entityAs[String])
```

going to the top with

```
doc.hcursor.downArray.downField("c").delete.top
```

will give you

```scala
Some([
  {
    "a" : "a",
    "b" : "b"
  },
  {
    "a" : "a1",
    "b" : "b1",
    "c" : "c1"
  }
])
```

But as I understand, you want to remove the next "c" too. That would be

```scala
doc.hcursor.downArray.downField("c").delete.right.downField("c").delete.top
```

or, to delete them all

```
def removeCs(element: ACursor): ACursor = {
  val deleted = element.downField("c").delete
  val focus = deleted.success.getOrElse(element)
  focus.right.success match {
    case Some(next) => removeCs(next)
    case None => focus
  }
}

removeCs(doc.hcursor.downArray).top
```